# Using group by and sort by in nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash, group-by

I have a function:

```
tracks.group_by { |t| t[:track].track_category }
```

Which creates a hash:

```
{ 

 #<TrackCategory id: 2, order: 0> => 
  [{:track => 
     #<Track promo_order: 2>,
    :order => 2},
   {:track => 
     #<Track promo_order: 2>,
    :order => 1}],

 #<TrackCategory id: 1, order: 1> => 
  [{:track => 
     #<Track promo_order: 2>,
    :order => 2},
   {:track => 
     #<Track promo_order: 2>,
    :order => 1}]
}
```

I've been trying to sort the TrackCategories by order, and inside that sort the Tracks by promo_order.

This keeps giving me errors, and I'm positive I'm doing something wrong

```
tracks.group_by { |t| t[:track].track_category }.sort_by { |t| t[:order] }.sort_by { |t| t[:promo_order] }
```

Comment: What errors is it giving you? How are the objects laid out? (i.e. what are their relationships to other things?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a key-value pair which came from `group_by` and was coerced as an array to `sort_by`, and then trying to access a key in the array, which of course doesn't exist.

In other words, you're mistaking the input used in sort_by. In the first `sort_by`, `|t|` is a hash key-pair generated by group_by and coerced into a array of the form `[k,v]`. In your case, `t` is:

```
[ #<TrackCategory id: 2, order: 0>,
  [{:track => 
     #<Track promo_order: 2>,
    :order => 2},
   {:track => 
     #<Track promo_order: 2>,
    :order => 1}],
 #...
]
```

So what you want is to decompose the array in its elements so you can get the ones you want, something like:

```
tracks.group_by { |t| t[:track].track_category }
  .sort_by { |t, _| t[:order] } # here you're sorting by TrackCategory#[:order]
```

And something similar on the second line, but using `[:promo_order]` instead.